# andengine gesture

Tags: android, andengine, gesture

I try to drawn gesture in andengine
i create this:

```
    protected int getLayoutID() {
    return R.layout.gesture;
}

protected int getRenderSurfaceViewID() {
    return R.id.gesture_rendersurfaceview;
}

protected int getGestureOverlayViewID() {
    return R.id.gesture_GestureOverlayView;
}
```

in Gesture.xml i this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.RenderSurfaceView 
                                    android:id="@+id/gesture_rendersurfaceview"
            android:layout_width="240px" 
            android:layout_height="240px"
            android:layout_margin="10px" />

   <org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.GestureOverlayView 
   android:id="@+id/gesture_GestureOverlayView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1.0" />

 </AbsoluteLayout>
```

i use this, is standard code normally

```
 mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
    if (!mLibrary.load()) {
        finish();
    }

    GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gesture_GestureOverlayView);

    gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
```

but the program crashes in line GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gesture_GestureOverlayView);, how adapt in AndEngine please?

Comment: i find this http://www.andengine.org/forums/post48677.html#p48677 but How added andengine surface renderer to GestureOverlayView ?

Answer (score 1):

There is already a gesture detector class available in and-engine

`org.andengine.input.touch.detector.SurfaceGestureDetectorAdapter`

You can use it for getting swipe detection and your requirement is not clear But may be this will help you.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle pSavedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(pSavedInstanceState);

        this.mSGDA = new SurfaceGestureDetectorAdapter(this) {

            @Override
            protected boolean onSingleTap() {
                // onSurfaceGesture("Tap");
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean onSwipeDown() {
                onSurfaceGesture("Swipe Down");
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean onSwipeLeft() {
                onSurfaceGesture("Swipe Left");
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean onSwipeRight() {
                onSurfaceGesture("Swipe Right");
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean onSwipeUp() {
                onSurfaceGesture("Swipe Up");
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean onDoubleTap() {
                // onSurfaceGesture("Double Tap");
                return false;
            }

        };

        this.mSGDA.setEnabled(true);
}
```

and to register it

`this.mScene.setOnSceneTouchListener(this.mSGDA);`

Answer (score 0):

Given the fairly limited information about the you've given, your `GestureOverlayView` constructor might be broken.